# Retrieving an instance from the Angular injector at runtime

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When my application is running, I would like to open the console and get hold of an object instance from the injector. Is this possible?

Something like:

```
var service = angular.injector.get('my-service'); // This does not work
```

Comment: angular.injector is a method not a property. 
Check this for the proper usage of injector. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector <br>
use `ng-inspect` or `ng-console` chrome extensions to debug services from console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
var service = angular.element(document.documentElement).injector().get('my-service');
```

In above snippet you should pass application root DOM element into `angular.element`. For this example, I used `document.documentElement` which is `html` element.

Also note, that you can't use `angular.injector()` directly, as you need to use the injector instance used for application boostraping. To retrieve this injector instance object you need to call `injector` method of the corresponding `angular.element` instance.